# how to set ctrl+[ instead of escape in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I use vim mode in sublime text 3, I want to use `ctrl+[` instead of `esc`.

This is my keymap config:

```
[
    // vim_mode
    // exit insert mode, same to 'esc'
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [ 
            "single_selection", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "hide_overlay", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "has_prev_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "overlay_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "hide_panel",
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "popup_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+["], 
        "command": 
        [
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
            "hide_overlay", 
            "clear_fields", 
            "hide_popup", 
            "hide_auto_complete", 
            "exit_insert_mode", 
            "enter_visual_mode",
            "hide_panel",
        ],
        "args": { "cancel": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    {
        // auto_complete
        // use tab to forward to next completion source
        "keys": ["ctrl+n"],
        "command": "move",
        "args": { "by": "lines", "forward": true },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        ],
    },
    {
        // auto_complete
        // use tab to backward to prev completion source
        "keys": ["ctrl+p"],
        "command": "move",
        "args": { "by": "lines", "forward": false },
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        ],
    },
]
```

after I map all `escape commands` and `vim exit insert mode` to `ctrl+[`, when I type this:
[image]

the `ctrl+[` doesn't work, the selection will not disappear until I press the `esc`.

why `ctrl+[` cannot make it disappear ?

Comment: You create your keybinding the wrong way the `command` must be a string and not an array. Just copy all `esc` keybinding from the default keybindings to your user keybindings and change `esc` to `ctrl+[`. In addition copy the escape keybinding from the vintage packe and paste it at the precedence you want it to have. If you want to escape to a "clean" normal mode with one keypress this is also possible, but not like this.

Comment: @r-stein, please tell me, how to escape to a "clean" normal mode with one esc press. that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single command to exit to a clean command mode by installing [ChainOfCommand](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) (or creating a macro) and just call all "exit" commands at once. Just install it and paste this into your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+["],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["hide_overlay"],
            ["hide_popup"],
            ["hide_auto_complete"],
            ["hide_panel", {"cancel": true}],
            ["clear_fields"],
            ["single_selection"],
            ["exit_insert_mode"],
            ["exit_visual_mode"],
        ]
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `"vintage_ctrl_keys": true,` to your settings.